# Trying to edit the width of column in exported excel sheet Dojo.grid.enhancedGrid

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm trying to increase the width of the exported Excel sheet in the `dojox.grid.enhancedGrid.plugins.Exporter`, but it seems that I can't find that kind of info in the documentation.

Here's the code for the grid that I'm trying to edit.

```
var tableGrid = new EnhancedGrid({
    id: "reportData",
    structure: layout,
    autoWidth: true,
    autoHeight: true,
    noDataMessage:"No data found",
    plugins: {
        printer: true,
        exporter: true,
        pagination: {
            pageSizes: ["10", "50", "100", "All"],
            defaultPageSize: 50,
            description: true,
            sizeSwitch: true,
            pageStepper: true,
            gotoButton: true,
            maxPageStep: 4,
            position: "top"
        }
    }
},this.ReportData).startup();
```

Answer (score 0):

The width of the Tablecells can be managed with via the Layout of the Grid like this:

```
var layoutMP = [[
        {name:"Field1", field: "fieldName",'width': '150px'},
        {name:"Field2", field: "fieldname2",'width': '100px'},
        {name:"Field3", etc....}
        ]];
```

This will be addopted by the export.